# What's the best way to re-render a normal table?

Tags: visualforce

I currently have a table with data in it supplied by merge field tags ({!account.name} etc ).

I'm using actionPoller to re-render elements on my page, but how should I rerender this? I've looked at dataTable and dataGrid but it seems they're iteration components and not suited to simply displaying data which is literally a few values.

Any input on this matter? Thanks for viewing.

Comment: Can you post your code what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap your table in an `apex:outputPanel` and refresh that.

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" id="panelToRerender">
  {!account.Name}, {!account.CreatedDate}
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:actionPoller rerender="panelToRerender" />
```

The `layout="none"` attribute will prevent the `outputpanel` outputting a `span` and potentially breaking your layout.